# Windows Phone 7 Information

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I need following information from Windows Phone 7 using C#:

In-built Storage Memory (Not RAM)
Phone Model
Operator Name
Whether Storage Card is installed. If yes, Capacity of Storage Card
Whether Carkit, Headset, Camera, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth is available
OS Name (Windows Phone 7)
Wi-Fi, Bluetooth - MAC Address, H/w & S/w version

While APIs can be used to fetch above information from Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN has several pages on this subject, not covering all of them but at least some.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: I have already gone through them. None of the above items can be fetched from these links.

Comment: Can DeviceName be changed by User? I guess it's something like Computer Name in Windows PC. User can change it. Let me know, if I am wrong.

Comment: Excellent. Any other API to get any of the above information?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily you can't request most of this information easily.

You really should explain WHY you want it. It sounds like you would just want to evilly spy on your users..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something sketchy to me...

Comment: No, however it contains the parameters to perform a device-specific attack.